# How to format strings differently in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some base.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.gmtime(1611161411.46177)),405.52,39,46,633],
    [time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.gmtime(1611161911.46177)),406.52,41,103,582],
    [time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.gmtime(1611161911.46177)),406.52,41,146,544],
    [time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.gmtime(1611161911.46177)),406.52,41,164,532]], columns=['Date','Balance',"In sell","Quantity","Profit"])
```

this is what it looks like :

[image: this is what it looks like]

I want to apply to each row:

```
df = df.style.bar()
```

This is how I would like to see my final table:
[image: This is how I would like to see my final table]

only with formatting of all rows. I ask for your help in this matter.

Comment: @bruno, I do not see the semantic load in your answer, I repeat, I need to get what is in the second screenshot, this table after formatting, I directly save from the file (on the 2nd screen)

Comment: then how do I apply the changes if I don't equate them for saving to a file?

Comment: if I was able to solve my problem on my own, there would be no need to contact here.

Comment: I have posted the answer. Feel free to modify it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
df.style.bar(subset=pd.IndexSlice[1:2, ['Quantity', 'Profit']], align='mid', color=['#5fba7d'])
```

---

[image]

Comment: Yes, I had the option to use this, but there were some difficulties with determining the maximum value (the sum of the last 2 elements)

Comment: Can you explain in details?